# Pandas multiindex duplicated only for particular indices

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, drop-duplicates

Say I have a Pandas dataframe with multiple indices:

```
arrays = [["UK", "UK", "US", "FR"], ["Firm1", "Firm1", "Firm2", "Firm1"], ["Andy", "Peter", "Peter", "Andy"]]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names = ("Country", "Firm", "Responsible"))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(4), index = idx)
df

                             0
Country Firm  Responsible     
UK      Firm1 Andy         0.0
              Peter        0.0
US      Firm2 Peter        0.0
FR      Firm1 Andy         0.0
```

I want to drop duplicated entries of the first two index levels (In the example, rows with "UK" and "Firm1" entries) and keep only the rows, where the third index "Responsible" is equal to "Andy". So I want to drop the second row in this case.

In pandas there is `drop_duplicates()`  but I don't see how I can i) apply it only on the first two index levels and ii) specify to keep rows with "Andy" and drop the rest (the function only allows for 'first' and 'last' as arguments)

I would be happy for inputs! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to remove entries if the first 2 levels are duplicated and `Andy` does not appear in the `Responsible` level: First use [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) for `DataFrame`, and then test both first 2 levels for duplicates with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), setting the `keep=False` argument for all duplicates. Finally, filter only the `Andy` rows by chaining another mask with the bitwise "`OR`" operator `|`.

```
df1 = df.index.to_frame()

df = df[~df1.duplicated(subset=['Country','Firm'], keep=False) | 
         df1['Responsible'].eq('Andy')]
print(df)
                             0
Country Firm  Responsible     
UK      Firm1 Andy         0.0
US      Firm2 Peter        0.0
FR      Firm1 Andy         0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple option, drop the last level and use [`Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html), then you combine it with any other mask you want to:

```
df[~df.index.droplevel(2).duplicated()]
# or by name:
# df[~df.index.droplevel('Responsible').duplicated()]
```

output:

```
                             0
Country Firm  Responsible     
UK      Firm1 Andy         0.0
US      Firm2 Peter        0.0
FR      Firm1 Andy         0.0
```