# pandas: mark duplicate rows using subset of MultiIndex levels, not columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with a many-leveled `MultiIndex`. Early on I need to mark certain rows to keep; in subsequent sorting and processing these rows will always be kept.

I have working code, but it's not very attractive and I'm wondering if there's a prettier / more efficient way to do it.

Given a `df` with a 3+ level `MultiIndex` and an arbitrary number of columns, I run this code to check for duplicates in the first 2 levels of the `MultiIndex`, and mark the first occurrence as the keeper:

```
df['keeper'] = df.index.isin(df.assign(check=df.index.get_level_values(0), check2=df.index.get_level_values(1)).drop_duplicates(subset=['check', 'check2']).index)
```

Here's a toy `df` with resultant `keeper` col:

```
                       0  keeper
lev0 lev1 lev2                  
1    1    1     0.696469    True
          2          NaN   False
     2    3     0.719469    True
          2     0.980764   False
     3    1          NaN    True
```

I tried `reset_index` but in the end I need the MultiIndex to remain unchanged, and moving those levels to columns only to have to re-create the very large MultiIndex again afterwards seemed even less efficient than what I have.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71645191/pandas-multiindex-duplicated-only-for-particular-indices

Comment: @rhug123 indeed that is related, thanks. I could make the `to_frame` answer work, although in the end my `get_level_values` solution is probably faster (altho not tested) considering my MultiIndex is 10's of levels deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as well. It is inspired by mozway's answer on the link posted.

```
keep = ['lev0','lev1']

~df.index.droplevel(df.index.names.difference(keep)).duplicated()
```

**Edit by OP:**

I timed the various solutions presented (and my original code) on a 1000x1000 df with a 10-level MultiIndex, and this solution (using `droplevel` and `names.difference`) was the clear winner, by over an order of magnitude. From fastest to slowest:

```
%timeit ~df.index.droplevel(df.index.names.difference(['lev0', 'lev1'])).duplicated()
72.1 µs ± 248 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit ~df[[]].reset_index(level=['lev0', 'lev1']).duplicated().to_numpy()
816 µs ± 3.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit ~df.reset_index(level=['lev0', 'lev1']).duplicated(subset=['lev0', 'lev1']).to_numpy()
12.3 ms ± 38.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit ~df.assign(check=df.index.get_level_values(0), check2=df.index.get_level_values(1)).duplicated(subset=['check', 'check2'])
12.7 ms ± 47.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.index.isin(df.assign(check=df.index.get_level_values('lev0'), check2=df.index.get_level_values('lev1')).drop_duplicates(subset=['check', 'check2']).index)
15.7 ms ± 59.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rhug123 and [the answer he posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71645191/pandas-multiindex-duplicated-only-for-particular-indices) I improved on my original code, using `duplicated` instead of `drop_duplicates`, negating the need for `.index.isin`. I chose not to use `to_frame` because my MultiIndex is 10's of levels deep and copying all of the levels just to use 2 seemed inefficient. Both of these solutions extract only the required index levels.

3 different options that worked, from slowest to fastest:

```
df['keeper'] = ~df.assign(check=df.index.get_level_values(0), check2=df.index.get_level_values(1)).duplicated(subset=['check', 'check2'])
df['keeper2'] = ~df.reset_index(level=['lev0', 'lev1']).duplicated(subset=['lev0', 'lev1']).to_numpy()
df['keeper3'] = ~df[[]].reset_index(level=['lev0', 'lev1']).duplicated().to_numpy()
```

After `reset_index`, `to_numpy` is required because the index no longer matches the original. The 3rd solution first drops all columns using `df[[]]` so that `subset` isn't required.